# C# Config order AppSettings before saving

Tags: c#, sorting, config, settings, appsettings

Is there a way to order the AppSettings by key name before saving the file?

What I've tried:

```
Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(Application.ExecutablePath);
UpdateSetting(config, "LocalLastUpdate", remoteSettingLastUpdated);
config.AppSettings.Settings.AllKeys.OrderBy(r => r);  //this will not work b/c it's just the keys
config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Minimal);


private static void UpdateSetting(Configuration config, string name, string value)
{
    Log.Debug("Updating Local Settings [" + name + "] -> '" + value + "'");
    config.AppSettings.Settings.Remove(name);
    config.AppSettings.Settings.Add(name, value);
}
```

Example:

```
<appSettings>
   <add key="LocalSettingsLastUpdate" value="9/30/2021 11:27:13 PM" />
   <add key="Printer_DefaultLogo" value="Y" />
   <add key="Signature_Width" value="300" />
</appSettings>
```

After I run code to add a setting to the config and hit save I get this:

```
<appSettings>
   <add key="LocalSettingsLastUpdate" value="9/30/2021 11:27:13 PM" />
   <add key="Printer_DefaultLogo" value="Y" />
   <add key="Signature_Width" value="300" />
   <add key="LocalLastUpdate" value="10/1/2021 11:27:14 PM" />  <- this should be at the top
</appSettings>
```

Comment: Have you rerun the code after making the changes in appsettings file?

Comment: @viveknuna, i'm not making the changes in the file manually.  I'm doing it in code above.  The setting gets added correctly in function: UpdateSetting(config, "LocalLastUpdate", remoteSettingLastUpdated);

Comment: Can you post UpdateSetting method too, pls?

Comment: Just try `ConfigurationSaveMode.Full`, just hit and trial

Comment: @Serge, it's posted now

Comment: @viveknuna, that didn't solve the issue

Comment: But... whyyyyy?

Comment: @CaiusJard some people suffer from OCD.  Some settings have prefixes such as (Signature_Width & Signature_Height).  This would be helpful if they were next to each other when trying to find them within a file.

Comment: Good heavens, I thought it was for some reason technical. Just select a  block of rows with the same indent level and press Shift+Alt+L,Shift+Alt+S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code was tested in Visual Studio and works properly

```
public void AddUpdateSortAppSettings(List<(string, string)> newSettings)
 {
 var configFile = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);

             var appSettings = configFile.AppSettings;

            if (appSettings.Settings.Count == 0) return ;  //error

            var settings = new List<(string, string)>();
            foreach (var key in appSettings.Settings.AllKeys)
            {
                settings.Add((appSettings.Settings[key].Key, appSettings.Settings[key].Value));
                appSettings.Settings.Remove(key);
            }

            for (var i = 0; i < newSettings.Count; i++)
            {
                var found = false;
                for (var j = 0; j < settings.Count; j++)
                {
                    if (settings[j].Item1 == newSettings[i].Item1) 
                     {
                     settings[j] = newSettings[i];
                    found = true;
                     }
                }
                if (!found) settings.Add(newSettings[i]);
            }

            var existingSettings = settings.OrderBy(i => i.Item1);

            foreach (var item in existingSettings)
            {
                appSettings.Settings.Add(item.Item1, item.Item2);
            }

            configFile.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified);

            ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection(configFile.AppSettings.SectionInformation.Name);
}
```

to use it

```
var newSettings= new List<(string, string)>{("LocalLastUpdate","10/1/2022 11:27:14 PM")};
AddUpdateSortAppSettings(newSettings);
```